# when I take a picture twice and display image in imageview, app crashes

Tags: android

the first time, there is no problem and it works fine. But when I hit the "take picture" again, then the app crashes. Here is my code:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivReturnPic);
Bitmap = bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
myImage.setImageDrawable(bmap);
```

I know that it specifically errors out on the following code:

```
myImage.setImageDrawable(bmap);
```

Comment: So what does the stack trace tell you?

Comment: i dont knw anything about stack trace, im a bit new. it runs fine on emulator.

Comment: Maybe this is a typo but `Bitmap = bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath)` should be `Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath)`

Comment: When your app crashes look into LogCat and see what error it throws at you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change :

```
Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath);
myImage.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```